# How can I associate one point layer to one line layer?

Tags: qgis

**How can I associate in QGIS one point layer to one line layer**

A sample scenario could be this one:

- A point layer "Valves" and line layer "Pipelines"
- Each layer should have its own set of attributes
- A "pipeline" has to begin and end in one "valve"
- A change in the "Valves" geometry implies a change in the "Pipelines" geometry, i.e., if I move a "valve", the "pipelines" connected to that node should follow the node wich are connected to

Comment: What do you mean by associate: join the attribute tables, build a relationship between the layers, something else?

Comment: I think that should be relationship (or somthing else). I want to do that you can put "Breakdown" points only on "Pipeline" line layer. In future i want to do analysis how many breakdowns we have on each pipeline type...

Comment: I think a little more detail is needed. Say you have a point layer that contains a location where a pipeline break occurred. Are you simply trying to build a relationship that assigns the correct pipe Id to the break point?

Comment: More details: I saw in one GIS software that is specialized in watersupply & sewery that there is an option when operater in office recives call and get info about breakdown location (street name, number...) he just click on pipeline. GIS programm pin this "Breakdown" point on "Pipelines" layer and then it finds nearest "Valves" that should be closed before workers can start with repairing pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Install the mmqgis plugin.

Use the tool 'create hub distance'.

The tool is ideal for that purpose.

http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Consider making a donation to the QGIS dev team.

Comment: i will try. tnx

Comment: this plugin dosen't solve my problem. I need something else

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only solution I have found is to develop a plugin that propagates the changes to the other layer through the `geometryChanged` signal.